# how to restric user of Certain role from certain page in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using built-in asp.net Roles and membership provider in my website.

what i want to restrict all user who is in role "Nurse" from page name

`doctorDiscussionBoard.aspx`.

help me how to do it.

i guess we will write the code in Page load method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like you suggest:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Nurse"))
    //Redirect
```

That method is in the `System.Security.Principal` namespace.

You can also do it in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="doctorDiscussionBoard.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny roles="Nurses" />
        <allow roles="Doctors" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
....
```